# How to add images to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add an image on top of multiple `divs` when the user clicks a button.

so

```
 ----------
|          |
 ----------
 ----------
|          |
 ----------
 ----------
|          |
 ----------
 ----------
|          |
 ----------

button
```

after click a button

oo means image

```
 ----------
|oo        |
 ----------
 ----------
|          |
 ----------
 ----------
|oo        |
 ----------
 ----------
|          |
 ----------
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do the div's share that would make this happen? Do the specified divs that get images share a class? Will it always be every other? The pattern is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go with a different assumption than "every other one".  Here's a [jsfiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/pDStc/)

This solution allows for any arbitrary divs to gain an image upon button click, so long as you've identified them or tagged them in some way. So...

If your DOM identified which elements should gain a picture through some class naming:

```
<div class="yes"> </div>
<div class="no"> </div>
<div class="yes"> </div>
<div class="no"> </div>
<button id="button">Click me</button>​
```

And with some CSS like follows:

```
.picture{
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/100/")
}
```

All you need is a function like so:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('.yes').addClass("picture");
});​
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I assume following html:

***HTML***

```
<div class="hasimg"></div>

<div class="hasimg"></div>

<div class="hasimg"></div>

<div class="hasimg"></div>
```

Then on button click try this:

***jQuery***

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div.hasimg:nth-child(2n+1)').append('<img src="" width="" height="">');
});
```

Here, `'div.hasimg:nth-child(2n+1)'` will select each odd `div` with `class=hasimg`.

To make that image top you can use some CSS like following:

***CSS***

```
div.hasimg {
  position: relative
}
div.hasimg img {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  /* and necessary config */
}
```

Just modify `CSS` as your need.

Answer (score 0):

You may better use `<table>` to get a stable layout like;

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Row with Index #0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row with Index #1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row with Index #2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row with Index #3</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I think you are looking for a solution something like;

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
$("tr:odd").css("background-image", "url('http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png')");
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/vABUS/1/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Comment: IMO, table's are meant for showing tabular data, not layout. This can be achieved just fine with CSS and no table.

Comment: Layout described is just four boxes. In what way does this need a table? (Genuine question, perhaps I'm missing something)